# What is the simplest circuit to measure RELATIVE RF signal strength with multimeter?

Tags: rf, antenna

I need to use a multimeter to align two low powered dipole antennas which are in the same room. Naturally, I cant hook up the antenna directly to the multimeter. Which is the simplest circuit to get relative measurements of RF signal strength with multimeter?

I found [this one](http://www.jdtechsales.com/measure-rf-voltages-with-a-multimeter/) online, but I'm not sure if it will get the job done. Would I connect one pole of the dipole to "RF" and the other to "GND"? And how would I interpret the output on the multimeter?

[image]

Comment: I looked at your online circuit .It should work .I built one with a half wave voltage doubler and Ge diodes when I had more Hair .

Comment: Seriously, buy a Max2015 or one of the similar parts from any manufacturer you like.  The parts count will be about the same as for whatever you could put together but it will work correctly and you can easily calculate the real received power from the measured output voltage.

Comment: @Autistic I remember both of those (Ge diodes, hair).

Comment: @JRE Those are nice if you have 20 mA laying around at/near the point of measurement. Some applications don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A schottky diode rectifier, the circuit you've posted, is the simplest way to read RF on a multimeter. Build it and see if it works for your power level and frequency, you may be OK.

You would connect the two inputs labelled GND and RF to the two outputs of the dipole. Note that GND is just a label, it doesn't need to be connected to earth, it really means 'the terminal against which the RF signal is measured'.

Read the output voltage without RF present. Any change from that means an RF input, and a larger change means a larger signal.

However, there are two issues.

a) The signal has to be 'big' enough. A simple unbiased diode is quite insensitive for small signals. Biassing it so that it always conducts a trickle of current, and then measuring the change of output voltage with RF, makes it more sensitive. For instance, connecting the +VE output terminal through 100k to -1.5v (a single AA for instance) with respect to ground would pull an adequate biassing current through the diode.

Rather than simply measure the output voltage, which will be sensitive to temperature and bias current, it's a good idea to have two identically biassed diodes, only one fed with RF, and measure the difference between the two outputs. The offset voltage on the reference diode will track changes due to temperature and bias current on the detector diode, making the measurement more stable.

b) The diode has to be 'fast' enough for the frequency you are detecting. Although schottky diodes are inherently very fast, as in they don't have the carrier storage times associated with junction didoes, they still have junction capacitance and package inductance, which attenuate the RF at higher frequencies. You can get diodes in surface mount packages, to reduce inductance. You can get microwave diodes, with much lower junction capacitance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Does the output current linearly represent the input current? How could you calculate the input current based on the output?

Comment: No, and yes(ish) respectively, depending on temperature (even when compensated). At low powers, the output voltage of a schottky detector varies as the input RF power (the so-called square-law region). At high powers, the output voltage of the detector varies as the input voltage. Its video impedance is so high and signal dependent that it's best to load it with a high impedance amplifier and measure voltage, rather than an output current.

Answer (score 1):

At high power levels, a multimeter with diode-type RF probe might respond.  Attaching the multimeter
to an antenna, though, CHANGES the power level significantly (alignment 
accuracy would be compromised).

A grid dip meter
picking up the signal indirectly
might work better (and it can be tuned for the frequency of interest).

A radio with 'bars' or other indicator of signal strength would be best.  Such a device
has an automatic gain control circuit that indicates the
gain directly (and signal strength by implication) in its bias voltages.

Depending on what 'alignment' you have in mind, this reference may be useful [Noise Bridge](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/noise-bridge-use-in-antenna-construction)